# Why is there a coasting phase between the second stage engine cutoff and payload deployment?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

[basing this question on the Falcon 9, Paz satellite launch on 22 Feb]

Hi, this is probably a silly question, but there is an approx 3 minute time difference between second stage engine cutoff and the payload deployment stage. Why is this needed?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Why is there a “coasting” phase in some space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4187)

Comment: possibly to check the achieved orbit and attitude; ensure there is no residual thrust; or to prepare hand-over of control from launch to operational teams.

Comment: Perhaps a better phrasing of this interesting question might be "Why was the coasting phase of the Falcon 9, Paz satellite launch only 3 minutes long?" or something similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a "coasting" phase in some space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/why-is-there-a-coasting-phase-in-some-space-launches)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, as it's asking about the coast between the _final_ cutoff of the engine and satellite deployment.  The other question is above coast earlier in the launch sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Three things happen in sequence at the end of the final burn:

- Check the orbit, which involves some measurement time to get doppler and/or radar readings
- Set the spacecraft attitude so it's pointing in the right direction for release (as opposed to the right direction for thrust)
- Do the pre-release operations on the satellites

What's needed in pre-release varies.  You want the satellites attitude control to be working when you release it, but there are some things (opening pre-valves, etc) that you don't want to do while the satellite is under acceleration. But generally, this entire sequence is just a couple minutes of work.