# Why was the Atlas V's SRB kept attached for 1 minute after burnout in the OFT-2 mission?

Tags: srb, atlas-v, cst-100, boeing

In Boeing's OFT-2 mission, an Atlas V is the launch vehicle. The solid rocket booster burns out at T+ 1:35 minutes, but the boosters are jettisoned at T+ 2:40 minutes. Why are the boosters not jettisoned immediately after burnout?

[Boeing OFT-2 NASA Stream SRB Burnout](https://youtu.be/gy6iam6NjsU?t=739)

Comment: Related,  and possibly a duplicate: [Why is there a "coasting" phase in some space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4187)

Comment: I don't think the advantages of a coast phase are applicable here. Just guessing, so not an answer: The Atlas V has a one minute delay between booster engine out to jettison to ensure that the boosters are indeed completely out of propellant. Suppose the engine out signal was erroneous; that some unburnt propellant remained inside. A premature jettison could shake things up and result in re-ignition. That might well result in a catastrophic collision between a rapidly accelerating unattached and uncontrolled booster with the launch vehicle. I suspect the delay was a safety issue.

Comment: @DavidHammen This is not during coast phase. Engines are burning throughout that 1 minute.

Comment: I realize that the Atlas booster operates throughout that minute. My guess, which was incorrect, was that the delay was to avoid recontact with a re-ignited SRB. The delay, as properly identified in @TrySCE2AUX's answer, is to avoid inducing extra vibrations during a period when vibrations are already high. SRB shutdown happens shortly after maxQ, so it's best to wait a bit.

Comment: The coast phase that occurs after MECO, with the main engine still attached for three minutes after MECO, does apply. But you didn't ask that question. The video claims that the vehicle is out of the atmosphere at that point. It is not. It is out of the thick parts of the atmosphere. The atmosphere extends for several hundred kilometers above orbit insertion altitude. The atmosphere is very thin at orbit insertion altitude, but it is still there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solid rocket boosters are left attached because they don't want to separate them during the phase of highest dynamic loading of the vehicle. The risk of something going wrong during this critical maneuver is just lower when the forces are lower.

It's only a few Words in the [Atlas V Launch Services User's Guide](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/rockets/atlasvusersguide2010.pdf) on page 33:

> The SRB jettison sequence is initiated after SRB burnout. **SRBs 1 and 2, if applicable, are jettisoned at a predetermined time dependent upon the dynamic pressure constraint.** SRBs 3, 4, and 5 are jettisoned 1.5 seconds later, if applicable.

"dependent upon a dynamic pressure constraint" are the magic words here.

Comment: I replaced the screenshot of the relevant text with the relevant text itself. Otherwise, the answer is unchanged.